# Is it safe to use 'setKeystoreType(null)' with Smack?

Tags: java, ssl, smack

In my smack implementation I set:

```
XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.Builder confBuilder = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder()
                .setXmppDomain(serviceName)
                .setUsernameAndPassword(jidParts[0], password)
                .setConnectTimeout(3000)
                .setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.required)
                .setKeystoreType(null);
```

So I can connect to my jabber server (SSL and has proper certs).

Is setting `setKeystoreType(null)` safe for my server? That's all I'm concerned. Because without it I'm getting a java.security.KeyStoreException: jks not found on my app.

Comment: @Flow sorry it's, 4.2.0